# Right size liquid tight conduit for #6 wire

Tags: wiring, hot-tub

I’m connecting a 240 volt hot tub with #6 THHN wire (using #8 for ground)

What is the correct size of liquid tight conduit?

1/2 or 3/4

My local hardware store only has 1/2 in stock. Will that be too small to run all 4 wires?

Total distance is about 10 feet from sun panel to hot tub

Comment: "Conduit fill calculator" in your search engine of choice.

Comment: Do you need a neutral?

Comment: Thank you Ecnerwal. That is what I needed to know. 1/2 can only fit 2 wires, 3/4 can fit 4 wires

Comment: @FreeMan - the actual ID of different types of conduit varies for the same nominal size, so you do need to check the type you are using, particularly if it's close (*i.e.* if it just passes in schedule 40 PVC it won't pass in Schedule 80 PVC...) so it is important to use the correct type of conduit in the fill calculator. Likewise insulation types for the wires.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very good question down vote reversed!

all the information is there needed to calculate or look it up in the tables.

Thhn #6 4 wire. Look in the code book
Informative annex C table C5 the smallest size is 3/4” liquid tight.

Yes there are on line calculators but this is a simple one. Almost all THHN is dual certified as THWN and several other wire types.